# Conditionally extracting range of lines between two patterns in Linux shell

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I see similar questions but not quite close enough to give me an idea how to proceed.

I am trying to parse Rector dry-run diff output, and only retrieve changes for files which had Rector rules applied to them. Rector wants to also apply a code formatting standard, resulting in many changes that look like:

```
-[whitespace]
+[whitespace]
```

These are not needed for my usage case. I am okay with them being part of output I retrieve if there are useful code changes also present.

In general the diffs can look like this:

```
1) path/to/first/file
    ---------- begin diff ----------
code
code
-whitespace
+whitespace
code
    ----------- end diff -----------
2) path/to/second/file
    ---------- begin diff ----------
code
code
-old code
+new code
code
    ----------- end diff -----------
Applied rules:
 * RectorRule1 (link)
3) path/to/third/file
    ---------- begin diff ----------
code
code
-whitespace
+whitespace
code
    ----------- end diff -----------
4) path/to/fourth/file
    ---------- begin diff ----------
code
code
-whitespace
-old code
+whitespace
+new code
code
-old code
+new code
-old code, no longer needed
code
    ----------- end diff -----------
Applied rules:
 * RectorRule2 (link)
 * RectorRule3 (link)
```

From this example, I would like to extract Second and Fourth files, as they had Rector rules applied to them, resulting in following output:

```
2) path/to/second/file
    ---------- begin diff ----------
code
code
-old code
+new code
code
    ----------- end diff -----------
Applied rules:
 * RectorRule1 (link)
4) path/to/fourth/file
    ---------- begin diff ----------
code
code
-whitespace
-old code
+whitespace
+new code
code
-old code
+new code
-old code, no longer needed
code
    ----------- end diff -----------
Applied rules:
 * RectorRule2 (link)
 * RectorRule3 (link)
```

The conditions are as follows:

- A file diff begins with `^[[:digit:]]+\)\s`
- A diff ends with `^\s\*\s`
- Ignore all files which do not have rules applied to them
- Capture all applied rules, not just first one

I was trying to figure this out using `grep` and `sed` using `regex`, but I can't wrap my head around it. Is `awk` potentially a better tool for this since it can use conditionals?

I have implemented this using a `Python` script to match lines and store them, but I am looking for Bash 4.2 solution that doesn't rely on another script to finish its task.

Comment: please add your attempts in question

Comment: There are hundreds of variations of this question in the archives, look around for a bit.

Comment: please update the question to include some of your `grep` and `sed` attempts along with the (wrong) output generated by each

Comment: why do you think a Bash 4.2 solution would not involve a script?

Answer (score 0):

Using SED :

```
sed -n -e '$b end; /^[0-9]\+) /!{H;b}; :end; x; /\n\s\*\s/{s/.//;p}; z; x; H' INPUTFILE
```

Based on the input you provided in your post, the ouput would be:

```
2) path/to/second/file
    ---------- begin diff ----------
code
code
-old code
+new code
code
    ----------- end diff -----------
Applied rules:
 * RectorRule1 (link)
4) path/to/fourth/file
    ---------- begin diff ----------
code
code
-whitespace
-old code
+whitespace
+new code
code
-old code
+new code
-old code, no longer needed
code
    ----------- end diff -----------
Applied rules:
 * RectorRule2 (link)
 * RectorRule3 (link)
```

Tested under Debian 11 with GNU SED.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Note that this uses commands specific to GNU sed.

Answer (score 0):

With a grep that supports `-z`, `-P`, and `-o` (such as appropriately-compiled GNU grep):

```
grep -zPo '(?ms)(?&s)((?!(?&s).)*(?&r).*?(?=(?&s)|\z)(?(DEFINE)(?<s>^\d+\)\s)(?<r>^\s\*\s))' input.diff
```

This looks for a rule `^\s\*\s` (subpattern `r`) between two diff starts `^\d+\)\s` (subpattern `s`) (or a diff start and the end of input (`\z`).

---

With any POSIX awk:

```
awk '
    ! /^[0-9]+\) / { s=s"\n"$0; next }
    { if (s~r) print s; s=$0 }
    END { if (s~r) print s }
' r='\\n \\* ' input.diff
```

If not at a diff start, just append line to `s`.

Otherwise, print `s` if it contains a rule, then reset it.

To match other whitespace, use `[\t ]`, `[[:space:]]`, etc.

---

With any POSIX sed:

```
sed -n '
    /^[0-9]\{1,\}) /! {
        H
        $!b
    }
    x
    /\n \* /p
' input.diff
```

If not at a diff start, append line to hold, then skip remaining commands unless this is the final line.

If at a diff start (or end of input), retrieve previous diff. Print it if rule found.